# What makes the Google Places API not autocomplete on my C# application?

Tags: javascript, c#

I recently started a project that requires me to use the Google Places API to autocomplete the places' addresses in my C# MVC application. I made a sample project on the side to first test out if the API works and it worked correctly, but when I tried integrating it with my main project, the search no longer returned any suggested places, meaning that when I enter a few characters, the places API is supposed to suggested a few places but it does not. There is no difference between the view code on the sample project and on the main project because I copied and pasted it.

I've already tried creating new credentials (a new API key) on the Google Console and adding them to my main application, and I changed the names of my properties in the class to match those on my view but there was no difference.

The sample application has this js code:

```
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            { types: ['geocode'] });
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }

    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=secretKye&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

And this is the main application code. This is the only thing that is different between the main and sample application code, that's why I didn't add the first script on this one:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=secretKye&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No, nothing. There are no errors whatsoever

Comment: You don't want to post your API key here